# property place-holder Spring equivalent for JSF2

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSf2 web application highly configurable. I need to be able to pass properties located in a configuration file(config.properties in the classpath) to the jsf 2.0 managed beabs declared using the XML configuration.
Here is an example:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>${config.myBean.class}</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>property1</property-name>
        <value>#{config.myBean.property1}</value>
    </managed-property>
            <managed-property>
        <property-name>property2</property-name>
        <value>#{config.myBean.property2}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

My question is how can I access those values from the config.properties and have JSF created the beans properly. I know I can do this in spring using the property-placeholder.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/config/config.properties" />
```

Is there a way to do this in JSF 2.0 ? Is there another solution to do what I want to do ?

Please help !! .

Answer (score 1):

JSF provides a very robust properties file management mechanism that's only slightly more involved to setup than what spring provides. To load a properties file (or a resource bundle as it's called within JSF)

1. Define a `<resource-bundle/>` under the `<application/>` element in a `faces-config.xml`

   ```
   <application>
       <resource-bundle>
          <base-name>
             com.me.resources.messages
          </base-name>
          <var>
              msg
          </var>
      </resource-bundle>
   </application>
   ```

   Where `<base-name>` refers to the package/directory structure in which you have your properties file and `<var>` refers to the reference variable that you'll use to access the properties in the file within your application. Ensure you have that directory structure accessible within the web app. My recommendation is to store it in a regular java package and bundle with your app.
2. You can now reference your property within a managed bean as

   ```
   <h:outputText value="#{msg['messages.error']}" />
   ```

   and in your managed bean

   ```
    ResourceBundle securityBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.me.resources.messages");
    String errorMessage = securityBundle.getString("messages.error");
   ```

Comment: @kolossus.That's what I have currently but it is not working. because 'msg' is not available at bean creation. What I really need is to access those properties during the creation of the managed beans. Any idea ??? Thanks.

Comment: @alpha2011 You could try the `@ManagedProperty(value="#{msg['messages.error']}")` option. Granted it's not as declarative as what you'll get from spring, but it's still clean